# Why does my Empathy work with wifi but not with wvdial on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, empathy, wvdial

I really need help for this issue . My empathy works well when I'm online using WIFI .. but it does't work when I'm online using wvdial. . in ubuntu 11.10, empathy works great.. any ideas to fix this??

Comment: :D ... sorry, my bad!!

Comment: No problem Kal-el ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's because Empathy uses NetworkManager(NM) to determine whether you are connected to a network but NM itself cannot see the network connection established via wvdial. Issue  the following command in a terminal to disable Empathy's dependency on NM for network connection.
`gsettings set org.gnome.Empathy use-conn false`
Alternatively, if you do not need NM while using wvdial, you may stop it  with `sudo stop network-manager` before launching Empathy. Other applications that depend on NM to determine network connection should also work properly, for example, Ubuntu Software Center.
To revert the changes, use `sudo start network-manager` for NM and `gsettings set org.gnome.Empathy use-conn true` for Empathy.

Comment: woww.... nice ...it works dude ... thanks a lot ... !!:D

but, does my empathy still work under wifi?? without reverting back the setting?